# Enable Trendline drawing button in MT4 via MQL4

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, mql4, mql5

I'm MQL developer. It's some days that I want to enable/disable some features of Metatrader4 using some keys. Specifically I want to Enable/Disable "TrendLine Drawing", "vertical line drawing" and "horizontal line drawing" buttons but I didn't find related info on the web. As I know we can do similar task by importing User32.dll and using 
PostMessageA(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam) function.

Can you help me which parameters will work for me?

Comment: Your question is too ambiguous. Please elaborate on what you mean by 'Enable/Disable "TrendLine Drawing", "vertical line drawing" and "horizontal line drawing" buttons'

Answer (score 0):

MT4 doesn't support enabling / disabling buttons on the tool bar. The best you you might be able to do is remove / restore the group of buttons from the toolbar. I will investigate this further in case you are unaware how to go about doing it.